# sql / mysql or Spark SQL - Recursively find maximum time stamp of all files / sub folder with in the folder

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL or Spark SQL question

I would like to recursively find the maximum date-time value of each subfolder and finally find the top parent's maximum timestamp. I realize we can use windows functions ( lag or something like that but need to find values recursively

```
Input

 File/Folder    Folder/File Ind    folder level ind            Time stamp

 /A             parent-Folder              1                   NULL  
 /A/B           sub-folder                 2                   NULL
 /A/B/1.txt     file                       3                   02-FEB-2021 8 PM 
 /A/B/2.txt     file                       3                   02-FEB-2021 9 PM
 /A/C           sub-folder                 2                   NULL
 /A/C/3.txt     file                       3                   02-FEB-2021 10 AM
 /A/C/4.txt     file                       3                   02-FEB-2021 11 AM
```

Output should display like timestamp value ( Null values replaced with maximum time stamp of each level)

```
  Output

  File/Folder   Folder/File ind    folder level ind         Time stamp
 
  /A             parent-Folder            1                 02-FEB-2021 11 PM
  /A/B           sub-folder               2                 02-FEB-2021 9 PM
  /A/B/1.txt     file                     3                 02-FEB-2021 8 PM 
  /A/B/2.txt     file                     3                 02-FEB-2021 9 PM
  /A/C           sub-folder               2                 02-FEB-2021 11 PM
  /A/C/3.txt     file                     3                 02-FEB-2021 10 PM
  /A/C/4.txt     file                     3                 02-FEB-2021 11 PM
```

Comment: the expect output is unclear, why second row come with `6 PM` and third row become `5 PM` from `8 PM` , I can't see any logic behind that output table.

Comment: my bad! corrected the data. basically, file records have timestamp and folder records will not have a timestamp. I have to find the maximum DateTime of all files within the subfolder and populate the subfolder time and finally find the maximum DateTime of all subfolder and update in the parent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a approach with `JOIN` and `Like` to reconnect the parent and child :

```
SELECT
    a.FF, a.ind, a.level, Max(b.time) time 
FROM [table] a  
    JOIN [table] b on b.FF LIKE Concat(a.FF, '%')           
GROUP BY
    a.FF, a.ind, a.level  
ORDER BY
    a.FF
```

the column name have been change (because origin name is long and I am lazy) but it is correspond with order.
here is [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cafa654dbb74e392c87fc0294342d9fc) for better examine that I use `int` for time column in pseudo data, but I think query will still work with proper time datatype.